# Make Emission Bloom From Behind an Object?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, emission

I'm perplexed why I can't get an emissive object to bloom out from behind another object. Any tricks to this?
[image]

The top frame shows emissive sphere behind matte black sphere. Lower frame shows how the emissive sphere won't show it's bloom straight on when it's behind the matte black sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bloom

is calculated post-process from brightest pixels, since second image has no any, there is not any info to be used for such effect.

Make object behinds slightly bigger, so thin rim around will still remains ...

[image]

[image]

### Volumetric

Instead of glowing *Sphere* you can use *Point* light placed inside a volume ... *Bloom* enabled too, to softness edge of front sphere.

[image]

- Add a *Cube* with *Volumetric BSDF* shader > *Density* 0.1
  (something small that just can catch a light)
- Add a *Point* lamp with Strength 10.000 W
  Important here is set **Custom Distance** (here 1.3)

[image]

Blend file contains both versions each stored per Scene.
[image]